# Websockets application development

Tags: c#, java, javascript, tcp, websocket

Im on the verge to decide which way to go. On one side i have jWebsocket framework which offers me fast startup with javascript - java (client-server) integration, and on the other is to use pure socket.io (client) with c# websockets (http://alchemywebsockets.net/).

My purpose is not to advertize, however i need some thoughts on this before i start a project that requires REAL TIME information displaying(broadcast included) on the browser and i need to handle big chunks of data so i suppose opening multiple websockets on a server will do the job for me ?

P.s.
I will have maximum 10clients at the same time connected.

Answer (score 0):

The [SockJS](http://sockjs.org) library is a good choice for in-browser WebSocket client. It automatically supports fallback to variety of browser-specific transport protocols.

If you decide for Java on the server side, then I'd recommend Spring Framework 4 ([here's an introduction](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)) which nears it's GA release (I think we'll see it before the new year) and has WebSocket *and* STOMP support built in.